# UserControlVIewModel работа со свойствами UserControl

Tags: wpf, mvvm, usercontrol

Имеется главная MainViewModel и MyUserControl(у него своя ViewModel).

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> StringList;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        StringList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
}
```

Допустим необходимо передать коллекцию строк из MainViewModel в UserControl.

```
<Window x:Class="UCandVM.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UCandVM"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl Items="{Binding StringList}"></local:MyUserControl>
</Grid>
```

как получить коллекцию StringList во ViewModel-и MyUserControl-а?

```
public class MyUserControlVM
{
    //здесь работать с Items который приходит от MyUserControl
}
```

**UPD1**

> Но вопрос ещё вот в чём: зачем другому контролу видеть те же Items? Какой объект этот контрол визуализирует? Если это тот же объект, то и VM та же. Если это другой объект, почему у двух объектов общая часть?

Отвечаю на вопрос, да это другой объект.

Может быть такое что несколько `UserControl`-ов принимают одни и те же данные и обрабатывают их по своему в своих VM, затем выводят результат во `View`:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyUserControl Items="{Binding StringList}"></local:MyUserControl>
        <local:MyUserControl2 Items="{Binding StringList}"></local:MyUserControl2>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Добавим еще один `MyUserControl2`(со своей VM), который также принимает коллекцию StringList из MainVM. 
Каждый контрол по-своему обрабатывает принимаемую коллекцию, и выводит во `View` результат обработки.

Первый `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="UCandVM.MyUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UCandVM"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="root">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyUserControlVM></local:MyUserControlVM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Результат обработки UC1:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding result}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Второй `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="UCandVM.MyUserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UCandVM"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="root"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MyUserControl2VM></local:MyUserControl2VM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Результат обработки UC2:"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding result}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

В итоге для того чтобы работал `UserControl` ему нужно передать некую информацию из MainVM, затем работать с ней во `VM`-контрола.
Собственно как обращаться к этой некой информации во `VM` контрола?
Или как получить данные от `DependecyProperty`(определенные в контроле) во `VM` контрола.

Comment: А где вы создаете `MyUserControlVM` и как его используете?

Comment: Не-не, вы делаете неправильно. Если у UserControl'а есть своя VM, то вы должны писать что-то вроде `<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding SubVM}" />`, где `SubVM` — свойство типа `MyUserControlVM` в `MainViewModel`.

Comment: @andreycha, 'MyUserControlVM' отдельный класс,  в 'MainViewModel' нет свойства типа MyUserControlVM. Привязываюсь к нему так, '<UserControl.DataContext><local:MyUserControlVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>'

Comment: @VladD, в таком случае насколько я понимаю 'Items' должен лежать внутри 'SubVM' и не будет возможности передать его в другие контролы, у которых другие VM?

Comment: @S.KosT: Технически не обязательно. Если несколько различных VM содержат ссылку на _одну и ту же_ коллекцию, то их View смогут с ней работать. Но вопрос ещё вот в чём: _зачем_ другому контролу видеть те же Items? Какой объект этот контрол визуализирует? Если это тот же объект, то и VM та же. Если это другой объект, почему у двух объектов общая часть? (Давайте думать в объектно-ориентированных терминах.)

Comment: @VladD, ответил на ваш вопрос, попытался привести понятный пример(UPD1).

Comment: @S.KosT: У вас в коде проблема: вы задаёте DataContext прямо внутри контрола! Так делать не стоит, ведь при этом он у вас будет не связан с внешним миром. Вы должны устанавливать DataContext **снаружи**, как в моём первом комментарии.

Comment: @S.KosT: При этом вы сможете в различные VM положить общую коллекцию.

Comment: @VladD, Я сделал так как вы сказали, у меня все получилось. Я получил что хотел. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @S.KosT: Отлично, тогда оформлю в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём: вы задаёте `DataContext` прямо внутри контрола! Так делать не стоит, ведь при этом он у вас будет не связан с внешним миром. Вы должны устанавливать `DataContext` снаружи, как-то так:

```
<local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding SubVM}" />
```

где `SubVM` — свойство типа `MyUserControlVM` в `MainViewModel`.

Если несколько контролов должны иметь доступ к общей коллекции, положите ссылку на **одну и ту же** коллекцию в их VM. Если вы создаёте подчинённые VM не из XAML'а, а вручную, вы можете правильно инициализировать их и связать нужным вам образом.